# Dual Boot System File Issues with /Etc/ Hosts and Profile

Tags: linux, filesystems, windows, etc

I've done my first dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. While I used to have a Linux only set up, my current job needs me to interact with Windows software regularly. So, I've had two significant issues with my file system now and I'm wondering if this is a common problem with dual boots. I've solved the first problem, but now that I've found the second issue, I'm wondering if there's something I should have installed to make this smoother.

Okay. I was having serious install issues for a while, lots of permission denied stuff. It turned out that in Windows, my file system had lost the host name. So, I fixed etc/hosts/ and etc/hostname and my permissions went back to working. The Linux system files didn't have any problems, I checked on them. For those of you wondering, I gave Linux and Windows diff host names because stack overflow recommended it.

Now, I am having IP address problems. Specifically, I enter `ipconfig /all` and get 'ipconfig not found`. I've found a recommendation to fix my path in etc/profile.d, which I intend to try. However, does anyone know if these failures indicate something I should be doing to fix the /etc/ file generally? Does it normally go haywire after a dual boot? I'd love to stop fixing a brand new machine with file system problems.

Comment: `ipconfig` is a Windows command; the Linux analogue was `ifconfig`; it is more currently a subset of `ip` (e. g. `ip addr` or `ip link`).

Comment: Thank you.  For the problem, I am in a bash in ubuntu for windows and I have now tried `ifconfig`.  This seems to have fixed the problem!  Thanks again.